# Get the HTML result even if we get an exception with this code

Tags: c#

I would like to return the HTML result of a page with this code below, even if I get a 403 response code for example, so if it throw an exception.

This is the current code I have, and as you can see I would like to return the HTML result of the page when an exception is throwed too.

```
    public string authenticate(string user, string pass)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");

            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"agent\":{\"name\":\"Minecraft\",\"version\":1},\"username\":\"" + user + "\",\"password\":\"" + pass + "\",\"clientToken\":\"6c9d237d-8fbf-44ef-b46b-0b8a854bf391\"}";

                writer.Write(json);
                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();

                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    return reader.ReadToEnd(); // the html result
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "the html result";
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help.